# Creating a dependent drop-down list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, array, widget, user-interface

I am trying to create a dependent drop-down list in Google Earth Engine that will respond to the input from the first list. I am basing this off an example provided by Google Developers... https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_events

Here is a snippet from my working code

```
// EXTRACT STATE NAMES TO A VARIABLE
var StateNames = SE_Counties.aggregate_array('STATE_NAME').distinct().sort()
var CountyNames = SE_Counties.aggregate_array('COUNTY').sort()

// SELECT A STATE FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var StateSelect = ui.Select({
  items: StateNames.getInfo(),
  placeholder: ('Select a State'),
  style: {width: '290px'},
  onChange: function getState(key) {
    print(key)
    var selectedpolys = SE_Counties.filterMetadata('STATE_NAME','equals',key)
    var selectedCountyNames = selectedpolys.aggregate_array('COUNTY').sort()
    print(selectedCountyNames)
    
    // PASS THE COUNTY NAMES TO THE ITEMS FOR THE NEXT DROP DOWN LIST
    CountySelect.items().reset(selectedCountyNames);
    CountySelect.setValue(CountySelect.items().get(0));
    
    return key
  }
});

// SELECT AREA OF INTEREST FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var CountySelect = ui.Select({
  placeholder: ('Select a County'),
  style: {width: '290px'},
  onChange: function (value) {
    return selection
  }
});
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ddf5b8ac3fce09287e94e5d69971d042)

In this example, I have a list of state names and a list of county names. I would like to populate the second drop-down list with county names that fall within the state that is selected from the first list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a client-side list to the second select; you're giving it a server-side object.  Use evaluate to get it and a callback to set the value when the list arrives.

```
// PASS THE COUNTY NAMES TO THE ITEMS FOR THE NEXT DROP DOWN LIST
selectedCountyNames.evaluate(function(values) {
  CountySelect.items().reset(values);
  CountySelect.setValue(values[0], false);
})
```

Comment: I have always used .getInfo() to bring server-side data to the client-side, is evaluate a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @SeanRoulet They take the same amount of time, but if you use `.getInfo()` the user interface (entire web page) will hang while the request is performed, which is unfriendly and could take a long time. If you use `.evaluate()` it will not hang, but you have to write a function (`function(values) {...}` here) that handles being called _later_ with the data, which can sometimes be tricky depending on what else you're doing.

Comment: @KevinReid Thanks, the clarification has led me to understand a lot of examples that are on the tutorials, and why they use .evaluate()